# Ruby array, removing everything after > within subarrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

What I'm trying to do is a little more complex then what my questions asks but I can't put into words what it is I want to do and my terminology is probably wrong. Sorry. If I can edit the title of my question afterwards to better represent what I want to do I will do so.

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array = [
  ["bnb ><b>(BASE CABINET)</b>", "bnb ><b>(BASE CABINET)</b>", "1", "22\"", "22\"", "22\""]
  ["bnb >Edgebanding (sides)", "bnb >Edgebanding (sides)", "2", "22\"", "1/2\"", "1/2\""]
  ["bnb >Edgebanding (top/bottom)", "bnb >Edgebanding (top/bottom)", "2", "21\"", "1/2\"", "1/2\""]
  ["bnb >Panel (back)", "bnb >Panel (back)", "1", "21\"", "21\"", "1/2\""]
  ["bnb >Panel (sides)", "bnb >Panel (sides)", "2", "21 1/2\"", "21\"", "1/2\""]
  ["bnb >Panel (top/bottom)", "bnb >Panel (top/bottom)", "1", "22\"", "21 1/2\"", "1/2\""]
  ["bnb >Top (front/back)", "bnb >Top (front/back)", "2", "22\"", "3\"", "1/2\""]
  ["bnb >Top (sides)", "bnb >Top (sides)", "2", "15 1/2\"", "3\"", "1/2\""]
]
```

What I'm trying to do is get this as a result is basically removing everything after the `>` in the first element of each subarray and and remove everything before `>` in the second element of the subarrays:

```
array = [
  ["bnb", "<b>(BASE CABINET)</b>", "1", "22\"", "22\"", "22\""]
  ["bnb", "Edgebanding (sides)", "2", "22\"", "1/2\"", "1/2\""]
  ["bnb", "Edgebanding (top/bottom)", "2", "21\"", "1/2\"", "1/2\""]
  ["bnb", "Panel (back)", "1", "21\"", "21\"", "1/2\""]
  ["bnb", "Panel (sides)", "2", "21 1/2\"", "21\"", "1/2\""]
  ["bnb", "Panel (top/bottom)", "1", "22\"", "21 1/2\"", "1/2\""]
  ["bnb", "Top (front/back)", "2", "22\"", "3\"", "1/2\""]
  ["bnb", "Top (sides)", "2", "15 1/2\"", "3\"", "1/2\""]
]
```

and here's what I've got so far as code:

```
val = 0
@test_list = []
test.each do |comp|
  new_list = test[val]
  new_list.map! { |element| element.gsub(/\s\>.*/, '') }
  comp = comp[0]
  @test_list.push(new_list)
  val = val + 1
end
```

which removes everything after the `>` but it does it in both the first and second elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use regular expressions when confronted with a problem :) Sometimes a simple [`String#split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) will do.

```
source_array = [
  ["bnb ><b>(BASE CABINET)</b>", "bnb ><b>(BASE CABINET)</b>", "1", "22\"", "22\"", "22\""],
  ["bnb >Edgebanding (sides)", "bnb >Edgebanding (sides)", "2", "22\"", "1/2\"", "1/2\""],
  ["bnb >Edgebanding (top/bottom)", "bnb >Edgebanding (top/bottom)", "2", "21\"", "1/2\"", "1/2\""],
  ["bnb >Panel (back)", "bnb >Panel (back)", "1", "21\"", "21\"", "1/2\""],
  ["bnb >Panel (sides)", "bnb >Panel (sides)", "2", "21 1/2\"", "21\"", "1/2\""],
  ["bnb >Panel (top/bottom)", "bnb >Panel (top/bottom)", "1", "22\"", "21 1/2\"", "1/2\""],
  ["bnb >Top (front/back)", "bnb >Top (front/back)", "2", "22\"", "3\"", "1/2\""],
  ["bnb >Top (sides)", "bnb >Top (sides)", "2", "15 1/2\"", "3\"", "1/2\""]
]

target_array = [
  ["bnb", "<b>(BASE CABINET)</b>", "1", "22\"", "22\"", "22\""],
  ["bnb", "Edgebanding (sides)", "2", "22\"", "1/2\"", "1/2\""],
  ["bnb", "Edgebanding (top/bottom)", "2", "21\"", "1/2\"", "1/2\""],
  ["bnb", "Panel (back)", "1", "21\"", "21\"", "1/2\""],
  ["bnb", "Panel (sides)", "2", "21 1/2\"", "21\"", "1/2\""],
  ["bnb", "Panel (top/bottom)", "1", "22\"", "21 1/2\"", "1/2\""],
  ["bnb", "Top (front/back)", "2", "22\"", "3\"", "1/2\""],
  ["bnb", "Top (sides)", "2", "15 1/2\"", "3\"", "1/2\""]
]

arr = source_array.map do |a|
  [
   a[0].split('>').first.strip,
   a[1].split('>', -1)[1..-1].join('>')
  ] + a[2..-1]
end

arr == target_array # => true
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio! Just leanrt something new :)

Comment: I'm still very new to programming, I've never used String#split or even new what it did.:)

Answer (score 0):

`Array.each_with_index` is probably what you want. With index check, we can determine if it is the first or the second

```
arr=[
["bnb ><b>(BASE CABINET)</b>", "bnb ><b>(BASE CABINET)</b>", "1", "22\"", "22\"", "22\""],
["bnb >Edgebanding (sides)", "bnb >Edgebanding (sides)", "2", "22\"", "1/2\"", "1/2\""],
["bnb >Edgebanding (top/bottom)", "bnb >Edgebanding (top/bottom)", "2", "21\"", "1/2\"", "1/2\""],
["bnb >Panel (back)", "bnb >Panel (back)", "1", "21\"", "21\"", "1/2\""],
["bnb >Panel (sides)", "bnb >Panel (sides)", "2", "21 1/2\"", "21\"", "1/2\""],
["bnb >Panel (top/bottom)", "bnb >Panel (top/bottom)", "1", "22\"", "21 1/2\"", "1/2\""],
["bnb >Top (front/back)", "bnb >Top (front/back)", "2", "22\"", "3\"", "1/2\""],
["bnb >Top (sides)", "bnb >Top (sides)", "2", "15 1/2\"", "3\"", "1/2\""]
]

new_arr = 
arr.map do |sub_arr|
    sub_arr.each_with_index.map do |str,i|
        if i == 0
            str.gsub(/\s\>.*/,'')
        elsif i == 1
            str.gsub('bnb >','')
        else
            str
        end
    end
end

p new_arr
```

This is a preliminary solution that works. You can always turn this into your own style, such as, change do end to brace, use map!, change if statement into the same line, etc.

Comment: Thanks texasbruce... I'll also give this a try and see what else I can learn in the process ;)